# Embedding image from file in groff?

Tags: pdf, groff, troff

I tried `.PSPIC image.eps` and `.PSPIC image.ps` after converting a jpeg to postscript on converthub.com, compiled with `groff -ms -p file.ms -Tpdf > file.pdf`, and it shows up as a box with the correct dimensions but just the file name as a label and no image. That's exactly what [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701843/groff-can-i-embed-images) said to do,  but doesn't work. I can do text just fine, but don't know much about ps images. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using -Tps so that the backend is `grops` which handles this macro. Then convert with `ps2pdf`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

From the [`groff_tmac(5)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/groff_tmac.5.html):

> The following output devices support inclusion of PS images: -Tps, -Tdvi, -Thtml, and -Txhtml; for all other devices the image is replaced with a hollow rectangle of the same size.

You can use `-Tps` instead of `-Tpdf`, and then convert with `ps2pdf`:

```sh
groff -ms -p file.ms -Tps | ps2pdf - file.pdf
```